# Ending the lifetime of an object used in another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, language-lawyer, lifetime, happens-before

What can the Standard say about the code below?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    static_assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(float));
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    auto pi = new int{10};

    std::thread t([pi]() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            std::cout << *pi << '\n';
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        }
    });

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    auto pf = ::new (pi) float{};

    *pf = -1.0;

    t.join();
}
```

I'm especially curious how to (or, is it possible to) apply [[basic.life]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#7) and [[basic.life]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#8) saying

> Similarly, before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated or, **after** the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released

and

> If, **after** the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, a new object is created at the storage location which the original object occupied

respectively, given that [[basic.life]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#11) is saying

> In this section, “before” and “after” refer to the “[happens before](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.multithread#def:happens_before)” relation.

Does this mean that if the thread doesn't "see" the `int` object lifetime end, it can access it as if it was alive?

At first I thought that the program has a [data race](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.multithread#def:data_race):

> The execution of a program contains a *data race* if it contains two potentially concurrent conflicting actions, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other, except for the special case for signal handlers described below. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

However, there are no conflicting actions. By [the definition of "conflict"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.multithread#def:conflict):

> Two expression evaluations *conflict* if one of them modifies a [memory location](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.memory#def:memory_location) and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location.

and [the definition of "memory location"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.memory#def:memory_location):

> A *memory location* is either an object of scalar type or a maximal sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having nonzero width.

reads through `*pi` don't conflict with store through `*pf`, because these lvalues denote **different** objects and thus **different** memory locations.

I feel the program has to have UB, but don't see where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**[basic.life]/4**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#4) The properties ascribed to objects and references throughout this International Standard apply for a given object or reference only during its lifetime.

The term "during" is not formally defined, but it would be reasonable to define it as "after the lifetime starts and before the lifetime ends".

Now, the opposite of *happens-after* is not *happens-before*, it's "*happens-before* or is *unsynchronized-with*". Thus, an operation that *happens-before* or is *unsynchronized-with* the start of the object's lifetime, or that *happens-after* or is *unsynchronized-with* the end of the object's lifetime, is not performed "during its lifetime". To the extent such an operation relies on "properties ascribed to" this object, it exhibits undefined behavior.

On these grounds, I believe your example exhibits undefined behavior, as access to the object `*pi` is *unsynchronized-with* the end of its lifetime.

Comment: Do you want to say that _In this section, “before” and “after” refer to the “happens before” relation._ is not to be read as _In this section, “before” and “after” refer to the “happens before” [and “happens after”] relation[, respectively]._

Comment: Of course "before" is short for *happens-before*, and "after" for *happens-after*. I'm not sure I quite grasp what you are driving at. What I'm saying is this: access to `*pi` on worker thread does not *happen-before* the end of the lifetime of that `int` object; therefore, it doesn't happen "during" that object's lifetime; therefore, the standard doesn't define the behavior of that access; therefore, that access exhibits undefined behavior. Note that "`A` does not happen before `B`" doesn't require or imply that "`A` happens after `B`" - it's possible for neither to happen before the other.

Comment: Ah, now I see what do you mean. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing `*pi` in the thread after the `::new (pi) float{};` expression is evaluated results in undefined behavior.

From that same `[basic.expr]` section, [paragraph 5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#5) says:

> A program may end the lifetime of any object by reusing the storage which the object occupies

Once the storage allocated for the `int` pointed to by `pi` is reused to store a float, the lifetime of the object `*pi` has ended.  Paragraph 7 says that when the thread accesses that value, you have undefined behavior.

There is an example given in paragraph 6 that is doing the same thing that you're doing but without the thread, and comments that it is undefined behavior.

Common results of all this include the possibility that the loop in the thread may print the same value all 3 times (if it reads `*pi` once before the loop and displays that value), or you may get `10` once or twice, then the integer represented by the binary value for -1.0f.  But those aren't the only possible outcomes.

Comment: _"Paragraph 7 says that when the thread accesses that value, you have undefined behavior."_ That's true, but as I'm asking in the question, does **after** in this paragraph mean that it is applicable to the case when the access _happens after_ the lifetime end and not applicable if there is no _happens before_ relation between the lifetime end and the access?