# C++ Undefined Behavior in Boost lock-free freelist_stack?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, atomic, undefined-behavior, lock-free

It looks like there's undefined behavior in [Boost freelist_stack](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/boost/lockfree/detail/freelist.hpp), and I want to make sure I'm reasoning about this correctly.  For a given node, it uses the node memory to hold the stored object (of type `T`) when the slot is used, and a freelist_node when unused. Here I've extracted/simplified the relevant parts of the code (and added some comments):

```
//All in freelist_stack class definition:
struct freelist_node
{
    tagged_ptr<freelist_node> next;
};

atomic<tagged_ptr<freelist_node>> pool_;

T* construct (void)
{
    T* node = allocate_impl();
    new(node) T(); //A
}

T* allocate_impl (void)
{
    tagged_ptr<freelist_node> old_pool = pool_.load(memory_order_consume);

    for(;;) {
        //old_pool-> calls old_pool.get_ptr(), returning freelist_node* 
        freelist_node * new_pool_ptr = old_pool->next.get_ptr(); //B
        tagged_ptr<freelist_node> new_pool (new_pool_ptr, old_pool.get_next_tag());

        if (pool_.compare_exchange_weak(old_pool, new_pool)) {
            void * ptr = old_pool.get_ptr();
            return reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptr);
        }
    }
}
```

Suppose two threads enter this loop, and Thread 1 succeeds with the CAS and constructs a `T` (A). After the `T` is constructed, Thread 2 calls `old_pool->next` (B), using the **same** `freelist_node` that Thread 1 already obliterated by constructing a `T` there (A).

This is undefined behavior in C++, right? There is no happens-before relationship between the `T` getting constructed and the `freelist_node` being read at the same memory location. Not only is this a data race (non-atomic use of memory), but we're also violating strict aliasing (same memory location being used as different types).

Is this interpretation incorrect? Is there any way to guarantee that is safe? When this does happen we'll fail the CAS anyway and retry ... except since we're in UB-land it's impossible to reason about what the compiler might try to do. Perhaps the compiler isn't able to make any assumptions/optimizations in this context that might break this, so it happens to work anyway?

Comment: `A` would only happens after it success allocate, I don't see any problem with it

Comment: just a guess, I think you somehow confuse `pool` and `node` to be the same.

Comment: The class is an implementation detail. Where it is used it is made sure that `T` is a class type which has (essentially) a common initial sequence with `freelist_node`, except for making a member atomic. That doesn't actually prevent any UB, but it makes it UB that is not going to cause problems on reasonable compilers. I haven't checked the whole logic, but it seems to me that the library does intentionally do some stuff that _technically_ is UB, but known to work on implementations. There are also a few github issues at https://github.com/boostorg/lockfree discussing TSAN diagnostics.

Comment: @user17732522 OK, I didn't realize that's how it was used.  I'm actually interested in writing some code using a similar technique to this, so I'm really just using freelist_stack as an example of what I'm trying to do, since other people might already be familiar with it.  In my case T is generic and can be anything.

Comment: @user17732522 somehow I think `pool->get_ptr()` would return another storage location which seems not the case here.

Comment: But you'll likely have trouble using TSAN when using such "tricks".

Comment: @user17732522 _Yes, that's UB for the reasons you stated_ You, together with the author, should learn the definitions of _access_ and _memory location_, and you'll see that constructing an object on top of another whilst some thread reads the another is not a _data race_ (In short, _memory location_ is not a «byte/piece of storage»)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Yes, I did misuse both terms here. The question has also been tagged `language-lawyer` in the mean time, so someone can give an appropriate answer relating to the lifetime of objects. I don't think the UB conclusion changes though.

Comment: If you check what `T` is you will see that it is a `node` which as first member has `atomic<tagged_node_handle> next` - that's why this stunt works. However, I tend to agree that this is a strict aliasing violation.

Comment: Well, it seems that MSVC doesn't use strict aliasing because it would break windows headers, and gcc and clang can be compiled with "-fno-strict-aliasing."  So perhaps this code would be fine on these compilers using those?

Comment: Strict aliasing is irrelevant

Comment: @LanguageLawyer would you be so kind and enlighten us why that is?

Comment: @mpoeter I think, usually, ppl are not asked to disprove

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything better than answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59959442/ending-the-lifetime-of-an-object-used-in-another-thread

Comment: @LanguageLawyer What do you mean? I did not ask you to disprove anything, just to explain your reasons why you stated that strict aliasing is irrelevant. But the answer you posted actually explains that, so thank you.